# Rails - Getting Rake error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

When running `rake` commands, I get this error:

```
You have already activated rake 10.0.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 11.1.1. 
Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this.
```

How do I fix this so that I don't have to run `bundle exec` before every rake command?

I uninstalled rake and reinstalled, but it's still looking for an older version:

```
C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/rake:22:in `load': cannot load such file -- C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/rake:22:in `<main>'
```

Comment: `bundle update rake`

Comment: Tried it but it didn't change the default version

Comment: you can now `bundle exec rake ...` and it _should_ work

Comment: You are supposed to use `bundle exec`. If you are too lazy you can use binstubs or (what I do) this hack: https://gist.github.com/2called-chaos/c2ebcbac83fa3846670c  (which won't work on windows though)

Answer (score 28):

run

```
$ bundle update rake
```

that worked for me.

see the documentation.
 http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/bundle-update.1.html

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple:

```
gem install rake -v 11.1.1
```

Comment: `gem list` shows which version installed? Are you sure the right `rake` is in your path?

Comment: rake (11.1.1, 11.1.0, 10.5.0, 10.4.2, 10.0.2)

Comment: You might have the wrong one activated. Try removing all versions but the one you need: `gem cleanup rake`

Comment: gem uninstall rake -v 10.4.2
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    gem "rake" cannot be uninstalled because it is a default gem

Comment: Which version of `gem` are you using? That seems odd.

Comment: For some reason, it's defaulting to 10.4.2. Won't let me uninstall or anything...

Answer (score 1):

For me it was just that I needed to use `sudo bundle exec rake <...>`, maybe it can help someone else...

*(I was trying to install [concerto](https://github.com/concerto/concerto) on a RaspberryPi, FYI)*

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

1. `gem 'rake','10.0.2'` in gemfile
2. `gem uninstall rake`
3. remove `gemfile.lock`
4. `bundle update rake`

---

Simply remove your `gemfile.lock` and do `bundle install` :)

Comment: Did that too. It only has the latest version on it now, but still doesn't work.

Comment: @RayG I just update my post. Lets see if this works.

Comment: @RayG aw :\ Give this last 2 commands a try. 1. `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` If 1. doesnt work, lets try this as well `bundle exec rake db:migrate`.. If they both don't work.. Then I am not sure....

Comment: All the rake commands work just fine if I prepend 'bundle exec', but I get those annoying errors whenever I forget to. That's what I want to get rid of, but nothing seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

simply write this

```
gem install rake
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your Gemfile.lock for rake version, you should find something like

`rake (10.0.2)`

If you found the above then you have to remove your `gemfile.lock` then run bundle install again. 
And it wouldnt hurt to double check that you are on the right project.

Answer (score 0):

just write a command  starting with  `bundle exec`    example `bundle exec rake db:schema`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your installed `rake` has a different version to the `rake` in your `Gemfile.lock`. Just go in there, <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to search for 'rake', change the version number to the one that terminal wants.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the rake version you are using is not same as that in your Gemfile, you must make sure of that there's no difference, you can also take no more `bundle exec ...` with [rubygems-bundler](https://github.com/rvm/rubygems-bundler#how-does-this-work-ruby_noexec_wrapper)

```
gem install rubygems-bundler
```

next run (once)

```
gem regenerate_binstubs
```